# How to add border for html tr

Tags: html, css

Suppose i defined such a table

```
1    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
2    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
3    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
4    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
5    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
6    Chailie     23  Joker   Bass
```

Now i want to make it looks like this

```
|----------------------------------------|
|1   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|2   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|3   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|----------------------------------------|
|4   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|5   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|6   Chailie     23  Joker   Bass        |
|----------------------------------------|
```

as you see,i's like to add  border for a part of tr and make it looks like been grouped,
does anybody know how to achieve this?e.g can i add some kinda of css to set such border?

Comment: if you are fetching at server side you can do this by a variable and increment on every loop and check that if $var%3 == 0 then add css class which have border

Comment: my point is not about %3 == 0.so how to add the css that you mentioned?

Comment: i was telling the way to do at server side but diEcho's  answer is far better then my suggestion so do that

Comment: @Chailie  Edited your question. set border on right place

Comment: @Chailie See alternative method.. it will support most of the browsers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) CSS property

```
tr:nth-child(3n+0) {
  background-color: lime;
}
tr:nth-child(3n+0) td {
  border-top :1px dashed blue;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M2g5f/5/)

**More Updated** after reading your comments, try this

```
tr:nth-child(3n+1) td {
  border-top : 1px dashed blue;
}
td:first-child  {
  border-left : 1px dashed blue;
}
td:last-child  {
  border-right : 1px dashed blue;
}
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/M2g5f/15/)

**Alternative way:** ( Cross Browser compatible)

```
tr:nth-child(3n+1) td {
  border-top : 1px solid grey; 
}
table {
    border-right:1px solid grey; 
    border-left: 1px solid grey; 
}
```

[alternative method DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M2g5f/16/)

Comment: He wants borders around groups of 3 rows, not a background and border on every 3rd row's cells.

Comment: @Arbel I just provide the logic, how he can implement this

Comment: @diEcho right, he needs to know borders are not applicable on tr elements directly.

Comment: Yes,what i want is  add border for several tr,such that they will look like in one box

Comment: Yes,just tried,but it just have border at top and bottom,but on the left and right,it doesn't have border,if could add border for left and right,it would be more perfect

Comment: you can use `3n+1` if want border as a  box

Comment: @Chailie See Updated part of my answer.

Comment: Yes.That's exactly what i hope to see,it is very good and thanks

Comment: @Arbel see alternative method too

Comment: @diEcho The alternative is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zQJL6/)

CSS:

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.three{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="three">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="three">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chailie</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Joker</td>
        <td>Bass</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```